# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client axios next.js

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch, next.js, interceptor

> Same question on GitHub - https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2743

I have Axios in my Next.js project and sometimes I get an error due to interceptor when return the `Promise.reject`.

**Error:** Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

I encounter this problem when I make a request in `getInitialProps`. This happens very rarely when I restart the PC and open the page again.

**Axios instance:**

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://my-api.com',
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  },
})

instance.interceptors.response.use(undefined, error => {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    console.log("UNAUTHORIZED")
  }
  return Promise.reject(error) // <-- this cause the problem
})
```

**Next.js Page example:**

```
const Index = ({myData}) => {
  return data.map(...)
}

Index.getInitialProps = async ({req}) => {
  let myData

  try {
    const res = await API.get('/my-request', {
      headers: req ? { cookie: req.headers.cookie } : undefined, //setting cookie
    })
    myData = res.data
  } catch (e) {}

  return {myData}
}
```

Comment: Provide the relevant code that causes this issue.

Comment: @goto1, I think returning `Promise.reject` is causing this problem

Comment: `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` typically means that somewhere in your code you're trying to call the `res.someMethod` multiple times instead of once.

Comment: @goto1, when I remove interceptor this problem disappears

Comment: Yeah but that's something that `axios` related, so if you don't return an error it gets swallowed and is never handled. When you do return the error, perhaps the error handler is trying to do something about it by calling `res.someMethod` after you called `res.someMethod` somewhere else. The error you're showing indicates that's the case.

Comment: @goto1, it would be great if there is a solution :/

Comment: It's hard to say what the solution would be without seeing the relevant code. Figure out under what circumstances this fails and post the code responsible for it.

Comment: @goto1, I added an example page with `getInitialProps`, I get this error there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem disappeared when I upgraded Axios 0.19.0 to 0.19.2  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: curious why you are setting header in that "my-request", why not just set it once in the config? Is there a way to do that so ALL requests get those headers?